# Get quarter as QUARTER function does but using DATE_FORMAT

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to get quarter value from date as QUARTER function does, but using DATE_FORMAT function ?

I can't find any info related to this in mysql documentation.

There is just one part that says:

`% x  | x, for any "x" not listed above`

not sure if this could help.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: No, there's no way to do it.

Comment: You'll need to call the `QUARTER()` function and concatenate it to the rest of the formatted date.

Answer (score 1):

You can use quarter() directly, like:
`SELECT concat(year('2019-04-01'),' Q',quarter('2019-04-01'))`

you can get `2019 Q2`